# Sending and receiving data ? Ajax, Jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I would like to create is a attendance button. Once the user clicks on the button `+1` would be added to the total number of people attending. Is there any way of doing this without refreshing the page? I some how need to connect it to the database to add `+1`.

I've heard AJAX could be used and PHP but I have limited knowledge in these languages. Any help please? Here is what I have so far...

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    var parente = $(this).prev().text();
    var current_val = parseInt($(this).next().text());
    current_val++;
    $(this).next().text(current_val +' Going '+parente);
    // Here you can make ajax request to send the number of people who is going to those events
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="my_event">
            <span>Event 1</span>
            <button>I wanna go</button>
            <div class="output_event">0</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="button.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: What you need is a server side language (PHP being one) that can connect to said database and increment the counter when someone presses the button. Ajax is definitely an easy way to achieve what you want on the client side. Read the [document here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for that aspect.

Comment: jQuery's ajax method might be the best place to start. Try [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) to get you started

Comment: Thank you all looking into it. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

first step:
you must get value from input or other event

second step:
send that data using ajax method, like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Assessment/Save',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {A:QNo},
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("Test: " + data.result);
                    if (data.result == "T")
                        flag = true;  
                      successCallback(flag);
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    //alert("R: " + req + " S: " + status + " E: " + error);
                    alert('Unable to connect server!'); 
                   flag = false;  
                    successCallback(flag);                 
                }
            });
```

3. And PHP, example simple maybe like that:

   ```
   // to do with $data

   $result = "your result";

   echo json_encode($result);

   ?  >
   ```
4. and last, manipulation object html in success or complete ajax:

   var parente = $(this).prev().text();
   var current_val = parseInt($(this).next().text());
   current_val++;
   $(this).next().text(current_val +' Going '+parente);

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses. This is mind-blowing for me, I'm looking into your code. Its hard for me to understand I defiantly need to look into PHP and Ajax. But right now I just dont have time:(

Answer (score 0):

To stop the postback, try this.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){   
var parente = $(this).prev().text();

var current_val = parseInt($(this).next().text());
   current_val++;
$(this).next().text(current_val +' Going '+parente);    
return false;
// Here you can make ajax request to send the number of people who is going to those events
```

});

**return false;** stops the refresh

Answer (score 0):

I gues this is something you where looking for
http://plnkr.co/edit/0cKQtCzqT79WHSykDq0F?p=info

i would suggest to add classname so you can track the right element better

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" data-semver="2.1.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="my_event">
      <span class="myEventname">Event 1</span>
      <button class="myButton">I wanna go</button>
      <div class="output_event">0</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>



$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.myButton').click(function(){
    var myEvent     = $(this).closest('.my_event');

    var myEventname = myEvent.find('.myEventname').text();
    var currentVal  = parseInt(myEvent.find('.output_event').text());
    currentVal++;
    myEvent.find('.output_event').text(currentVal +' Going '+myEventname);

    var postData = {
      'eventname' : myEventname,
      'currentVal' : currentVal
    };

        $.ajax({
            url: './myUpdatePage.php',
            //method: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
              //Do something for successfuly received page
            },
            error: function (data) {
              //Do something when page isn't received
            }
            //, dataType: 'json'
        });

    return false;
  });

});
```